# How can I delete unwanted characters from dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I delete unwanted characters(\u20) from dictionary like this in python?

```
[{'title': 'title1',
  'tags': ['data mining\u20', 'data mining'
   'test\u20',
   'data mining',
   'test1']},
 {'title': 'title2',
  'tags': ['title2',
   'data mining\u20]
 }
  ]
```

expected dictionary

```
[{'title': 'title1',
  'tags': ['data mining', 'data mining'
   'test',
   'data mining',
   'test1']},
 {'title': 'title2',
  'tags': ['test',
   'data mining]
 }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the [unicode space character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm), which is denoted with the escape sequence `\u20`, using the `replace` method: `.replace("\u0020", "")`. The code below iterates over the dictionaries in the list, and then re-assigns the `tags` with an updated version removing those characters via list comprehension.

```
>>> ds = [
...     {
...         'title': 'title1',
...         'tags': [
...             'data mining\u0020',
...             'data mining',
...             'test\u0020',
...             'data mining',
...             'test1',
...         ]
...     },
...     {
...         'title': 'title2',
...         'tags': [
...             'title2',
...             'data mining\u0020',
...         ]
...     }
... 
... ]
>>> for d in ds:
...     d['tags'] = [ tag.replace("\u0020", "") for tag in d['tags'] ]
... 
>>> ds
[{'title': 'title1', 'tags': ['datamining', 'datamining', 'test', 'datamining', 'test1']}, {'title': 'title2', 'tags': ['title2', 'datamining']}]
```

Comment: thank you, but when I use enumerate  to fix it in ds It doesn't work: for d in enumerate(output):
    d['tags'] = [ tag.replace("\u0020", "") for tag in d['tags'] ]

Comment: I believe that is because `enumerate` gives you the index, as well as the element in the list. So you would want to have `for ix, d in enumerate(output)` or you would avoid enumerate entirely, and do `for d in output`.